# How to dynamically generate clickable links in ember using handlebars

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js

I am trying to generate click able links using emberjs framework. I have the model setup correctly and I have the following handlebar template:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="index" >
{{#each name in model.mymodules }}
{{#link-to name 'home' }}{{name}}{{/link-to}}
{{/each
</script>
```

The idea is to call modulename/home on each link. 
For ex: say I have 3 modules: "abc", "xyz", "123"
I want three links:

```
abc <a href="/abc/home">, xyz <a href="/xyz/home">, 123 <a href="/123/home">
```

What controller/route do I need to define for this to work.

jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/spkRa/2/

Comment: Do you want to link to the module object or simply create link like ' <a href="/abc/home">'s?

Comment: I want to link to the module object. If that's not possible in ember, I should be able to workaround just with creating links.

Comment: What do your application routes look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make use of ember resources for dealing with this problem

Read http://emberjs.com/guides/routing/defining-your-routes/

Example of application code should be something like this. JSfidle http://jsfiddle.net/NQKvy/291/

```
App = Ember.Application.create({
    LOG_TRANSITIONS: true,
    LOG_TRANSITIONS_INTERNAL: true,
    LOG_VIEW_LOOKUPS: true
});

App.Router.map(function() {
  this.resource('modules', { path: '/modules' }, function() {
    this.route('home', {path: ':module_name/home'});
  });
});
App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model:function(){
        return App.Modules;
    }
});
App.ModulesHomeRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function(params) {
        //returns an object from an ember array based on the property value
        return App.Module.findProperty('name',params.module_name);
    },
    serialize: function(model, params) {
        //updates the url with the param value 
        return { module_name: model.get('name') };
    }
});
App.Modules = Ember.A([
    Ember.Object.create({name:'aaa'}),
    Ember.Object.create({name:'bbb'}),
    Ember.Object.create({name:'ccc'})
]);
```

And hadlebars code

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="index">
  <ul>
    {{#each}}
    <li>{{name}}</li>
    <li>{{#link-to 'modules.home' this}}{{name}}{{/link-to}}</li>
    {{/each}}
  </ul>
</script>
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="modules/home">
    This is the home of the module {{name}}
</script>
```